# javascript looping changing values of other objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
    //console.log(itemArray[index].mats);
    var newMatArray = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < itemArray[i].mats.length; j++) {
        var mat = itemArray[i].mats[j];
        if (isInNewArray(mat.id, newMatArray)) {
            continue;
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < itemArray[i].mats.length; k++) {
            var mat2 = itemArray[i].mats[k];
            if (k == j) {
                continue;
            }
            if (mat.id == mat2.id) {
                //if (itemArray[i].id == 12005) console.log("adding " + mat.quantity + " of " + mat.name + " to " + mat2.quantity);
                mat.quantity = mat.quantity + mat2.quantity;
            }
        }
        newMatArray.push(mat);
    }
    //if (itemArray[i].id == 12005) console.log(newMatArray);
    itemArray[i].mats = newMatArray;
}

function isInNewArray(id, array) {
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id == id) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

So this loop is supposed to iterate over an array of items and remove/combine duplicate mats required for an item, each item is a json object with a name/id and a mats array of objects and each mat has a name/id/quantity required. For some reason if i iterate over only 1 item at some point in the array then continue on all the rest without combining it works totally fine.

It's only when its looping that changing the values of previous objects seems to change the value of future objects resulting in mats hitting quantities of 1.17555e^105 which is way higher than they should be. Does javascript do some kind of memory optimization that might be storing mat objects with identical values to the same location so when i increase the quantity on objects earlier in the loop it does so for objects later in the loop? Otherwise I don't understand why this algorithim works for 1 off objects but looping over objects and only ever changing one object at a time messes it up.

Edit: sample object below

```
{
    "id": 622,
    "bpid": 692,
    "quantity": 1,
    "name": "Stabber",
    "mats": [
        {
            "id": 34,
            "name": "Tritanium",
            "quantity": 48518335
        },
        {
            "id": 35,
            "name": "Pyerite",
            "quantity": 11828791
        },
        {
            "id": 36,
            "name": "Mexallon",
            "quantity": 40000
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "name": "Isogen",
            "quantity": 10333
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "name": "Nocxium",
            "quantity": 2778
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "name": "Zydrine",
            "quantity": 1244
        },
        {
            "id": 40,
            "name": "Megacyte",
            "quantity": 244
        },
        {
            "id": 20411,
            "name": "Datacore - High Energy Physics",
            "quantity": 8
        },
        {
            "id": 20172,
            "name": "Datacore - Minmatar Starship Engineering",
            "quantity": 8
        }
    ]
}
```

---

```
for (var i = 0; i < matsArray.length; i++) {
    var item = matsArray[i];
    var type = parseInt(item.typeID, 10);
    var index = findItemIndex(type);
    if (index > -1) {
        var mat = {
            id: parseInt(item.materialTypeID, 10),
            name: itemIDMap.get(parseInt(item.materialTypeID, 10)),
            quantity: parseInt(item.quantity, 10)
        }
        itemArray[index].mats.push(mat);
    } else {
        if (bpMap.get(parseInt(item.typeID, 10)) == undefined) {
            //console.log(item);
            continue;
        }
        var newItem = {
            id: bpMap.get(parseInt(item.typeID, 10)).itemID,
            bpid: parseInt(item.typeID, 10),
            quantity: bpMap.get(parseInt(item.typeID, 10)).quantityPerRun,
            name: itemIDMap.get(bpMap.get(parseInt(item.typeID, 10)).itemID),
            mats: []
        }
        var mat = {
            id: parseInt(item.materialTypeID, 10),
            name: itemIDMap.get(parseInt(item.materialTypeID, 10)),
            quantity: parseInt(item.quantity, 10)
        }
        newItem.mats.push(mat);
        itemArray.push(newItem);
        productsArray.push(newItem.id);    
    }
}
```

Would this array creation code create identical mat objects? Shouldn't each newly created mat be a separate object?

Comment: Just a little tip, it's good you have included code, and tried to figure this out. bonus points there.  But when explaining things don't be afraid to use paragraphs, reading a big block of text like that isn't easy.  It might also be a good idea to include some example input, and expected output.

Comment: Hey there, can you post the function `isInNewArray` as well as some sample `itemArray` object.

Comment: Your code seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/amullins/95a4ocek/

Comment: My guess is the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The problem is probably that some of the elements of `itemArray[i].mats` are references to the same object. You need to look at the code that creates this array (or maybe `itemArray`).

Comment: Added the array creation code but i don't see how it creates 2 mat objects that are the same unless there is some behind the scenes simplification if i make 2 mat objects with the same value and js combines them or something